# what is the dependency of simpleitk for maven?

Tags: java, maven, simpleitk

first time using maven, searching for 'simpleitk' in mvnrepository.com returns this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.itk.simple/simpleitk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.itk.simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleitk</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

this does not work as it is not in the central repository used by maven.
error: Could not find artifact org.itk.simple:simpleitk:jar:0.9.0

I find out that there are the tag <repositories>, where i can put a <repository>,
i tried:

```
<repository>
    <id>ImageJ</id>
    <url>https://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>mvnrepository</id>
    <name>mvnrepository</name>
    <url>https://www.mvnrepository.com</url>
</repository>
```

error: Could not transfer artifact org.itk.simple:simpleitk:pom:0.9.0 from/to mvnrepository (https://www.mvnrepository.com): status code: 403, reason phrase: Forbidden (403)

Can anybody help me plz?

i try to search a lot for 'simpleitk' dependencies for maven but cant find anything.

Comment: mvnrepository.com is just a web-based index. It's not a repository itself. That said, it does list what repos the artifact exists within. Look for 'Repositories' [on the artifact page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.itk.simple/simpleitk/0.9.0). In this case, ImageJ and Loci (never heard of either).

Answer (score 1):

Only the POM for Simpleitk is available from the ImageJ repository.  The binaries are not available there.  You can see that by browsing the repository:

https://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/releases/org/itk/simple/simpleitk/0.9.0/

As for solving the problem of how to get it working with Maven, unfortunately it might not be as simple as adding a Maven repository and dependency.  From [this post on the ImageJ list](https://imagej.net/pipermail/imagej-devel/2014-April/002002.html), it was asked:

> Does anybody know if there is a maven repository for SimpleITK??

And the response:

> Please note that what you ask for is not *exactly* trivial: SimpleITK is a
> Java (and Python) wrapper around a *native* library written in C++.
>
> Therefore you get all the wonderful problems of platform-dependent
> development: you need to make sure that you have the correct set of
> libraries, compiled for your particular operating system and CPU, working
> well with your other libraries (this is a particular problem with
> libstdc++ on Linux, where you cannot simply take your ITK libraries to
> another version of the same operating system, on the same CPU, and expect
> things to work).
>
> You also get the problem that depending on your platform, you need to have
> the libraries in a directory that is either in the system library search
> path or in a directory referenced by the PATH environment variable and/or
> the java.library.path property (that must be set *before* the Java Runtime
> Environment is started up, any changes after that will be ignored rather
> blatantly).
>
> These native libraries can be attached artifacts to the .jar artifacts on
> the Maven repository [*1*], but you will never be truly
> platform-independent anymore.

There are instructions on how to get it working with Java here:

https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/setUp.html#setup-java

---

However, I did find the simpleitk binaries in this repository:

https://maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public/org/itk/simple/simpleitk/0.9.0/

There is a JAR in there - but I haven't tried it.  It sounds like from all the previous info that simply having a JAR won't be enough because you'll need native bindings installed on your system, but you can give it a try by adding:

```
<repository>
    <id>scijava</id>
    <url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public</url>
</repository>
```

No guarantees it will work though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I manage to fix the maven problems, now iam trying to fix new error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SimpleITKJava in java.library.path

the tutorial explain how to fix this error, with an JNI lib, but where do i get this JNI lib? Do i get this by building SimpleITK with cmake? if so, how exactly? Cant find any answer, i already know how to set the Native library location in intellij.

Comment: i find this tutorial for building simpleitk: simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/buildingWindows.html and i'm building right now, hope i can find the JNI after this.

Comment: I managed to solve! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472858/where-do-i-get-simpleitk-jni-lib/76473695#76473695

Answer (score 0):

i fix it, at least the maven problems. Now i can import the lib and intelisense works.

my pom.xml with no errors or warnings:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
            <artifactId>vtk-java-all</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.itk.simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleitk</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jzy3d-snapshots</id>
            <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jzy3d-releases</id>
            <name>Jzy3d Releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.jzy3d.org/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>imagej.public</id>
            <url>https://maven.imagej.net/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>scijava.public</id>
            <url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```