# VTK java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, vtk

Trying to run/debug my project using intellij (windows), got errors like:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no vtk{Anything} in java.library.path
```

{Anything} can be any class of vtk i'm trying to use, for example:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no vtkRenderingCoreJava in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no vtkFiltersModelingJava in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no vtkViewsContext2DJava in java.library.path
etc...
```

I know this problem can be solved adding `-Djava.library.path=` to VM option.
I had a very similar problem with simpleITK and solved it: [Where do i get SimpleITK JNI Lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472858/where-do-i-get-simpleitk-jni-lib)

But my answer now is: How can i get JNI lib for vtk? Or native lib? Or any file that solves my problem?
I tried with this one but doesn't work: https://people.ece.ubc.ca/andrewkh/vtk-jni.html

then, i try following this: https://discourse.vtk.org/t/installation-of-vtk-9-0-with-python-java-wrappers/3325

i 'git clone VTK' and use cmake/visual-studio to make a build.
configuration is Debug x64 ALL-BUILD, using VTK_WRAP_JAVA=ON.
my build finish with no errors, but now i dont know what is the path to the file that i need to put into `-Djava.library.path=`